# Wrong row value when ordering with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

i have a table (10k records) with matches history beetwen 2 players like this:

```
+----+---------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+--+
| id | Winner  | Losser | Winner_new_rating | Losser_new_rating  | (datetime) | matchname |  |
+----+---------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+--+
|9999| Peter   | Wally  |           1200.34 |            1000.23 | 11.11.2013 | string    |  |
|9998| Peter   | Sally  |           1190.23 |            1123.23 | 10.01.2013 | string    |  |
|9997| Logan   | Demo   |            999.24 |            1222.23 | 11.11.2012 | string    |  |
|9996| Hex     | Wally  |            750.34 |            1333.23 | 14.07.2012 | string    |  |
|9995| Peter   | Sally  |           1180.45 |            1444.23 | 12.11.2011 | string    |  |
|9994| Wayne   | Wally  |           1450.22 |            1555.23 | 11.05.2011 | string    |  |
+----+---------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+--+
```

I am tryin to get from it history highest peaks grouped by player. Somehow when im doin this:

```
SELECT Winner, Losser, MAX(Winner_new_rating) AS maxrating, datetime, matchname
FROM
       ( SELECT * 
         FROM gamelist
         ORDER BY Winner_new_rating
       ) AS innerTable
GROUP BY Winner
ORDER BY maxrating DESC
LIMIT 100
```

I get almost fine output except datetime and matchname seems to be taken from random record.

Becouse i want to output like a ranking with history highest peaks i need proper game date and matchname (in real its tounament name), to show when this player hited his best peak.

ex what i need:

```
Greg  / 1455.99 / date of this game when he reached his max rating / matchname
Peter / 1234.23 / date of this game when he reached his max rating / matchname
Wally / 1199.22 / date of this game when he reached his max rating / matchname
Sally / 1173.11 / date of this game when he reached his max rating / matchname
Demon / 1011.22 / date of this game when he reached his max rating / matchname
Omen  /  999.13 / date of this game when he reached his max rating / matchname
```

...

Of course in datetime column is datetime format, this is just example.

No idea how to do it better. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What should the desired result look like?

Comment: Thats what happens when using GROUP BY, it picks one rows info, normally the first

Comment: As you have GROUPed the result, surely the `datetime` makes no sense to output

Comment: Warning: if you have `11.11.2013` on your database, thats NOT a DATE or DATETIME type column. Thats going to make other DATE oriented queries more complex unnecesarily

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "_highest peaks grouped by player_"? Do you mean the highest rating of each user?

Answer (score 0):

you are using aggregation function with column in select not mentioned 
 in group by  .. this is allowed only with mysql version prior 5.7  but produce unpredictable result

for avoid this you should join the aggreated  result

```
SELECT a.Winner, a.Losser, t.max_rate, a.datetime, a.matchname
FROM gamelist
INNER JOIN  ( 
    SELECT Winner, MAX(Winner_new_rating) max_rate
    FROM gamelist
    GROUP BY Winner
    ORDER BY Winner_new_rating DESC
    LIMIT 100
) t on t.max_rate = a.gamelist
      AND t.Winner  = a.Winner
ORDER BY maxrating DESC
```